# Big tar file. How to get UID GID properties of the root folder without untar all its contents?

Tags: linux, tar

I have a *filename.tar.bz2* file of several GBs in size. 
I want to get the UID and GID of the root folder that comes with the tar file, without untar the full content of it.

As of now, I can retrieve the info I need with a command like:

`tar xjf filename.tar.bz2   --to-command 'echo $TAR_FILENAME:$TAR_UID:$TAR_GID:$TAR_UNAME:$TAR_GNAME'`

... but I want it to stop after displaying the first line (root folder).

I need the `--to-command` option to display the uid and gid of the file (integers)

Is there a way to do that?

Thank you.

**Update 1**

I kind of found a way to do it. Next command displays first file in the stream and exit:

`tar xjf filename.tar.bz2 --occurrence --wildcards '**/*.*'   --to-command 'echo $TAR_FILENAME:$TAR_UID:$TAR_GID:$TAR_UNAME:$TAR_GNAME'`

**output**: `folder1/folder2/folder3/file.c:1004:1009:chuzo:adm`

Not sure why when I change wildcard to match root folder shows nothing:

`tar xjf filename.tar.bz2 --occurrence --wildcards '*'   --to-command 'echo $TAR_FILENAME:$TAR_UID:$TAR_GID:$TAR_UNAME:$TAR_GNAME'`

**output**: *empty*

Answer (score 1):

> I want it to stop after displaying the first line (root folder).

So pipe it to `head -n1`.

```
tar ..... | head -n1
```

Comment: Hi @KamilCuk. The problem is that tar process continues running. I'm looking for a way for it to stop after output first line (which contains the root folder info I'm looking for..)

Comment: Yes exactly. Pipe it to `head -n1`.

Answer (score 1):

The tvf option lists the info without unpacking it as shown in this example:

```
tar -tvf uploadprogress.tar

-rw-r--r-- chregu/staff   2276 2011-08-15 18:51:10 package2.xml
-rw-r--r-- chregu/staff   7877 2011-08-15 18:51:10 uploadprogress/examples/index.php
-rw-r--r-- chregu/staff   1685 2011-08-15 18:51:10 uploadprogress/examples/server.php
-rw-r--r-- chregu/staff   1697 2011-08-15 18:51:10 uploadprogress/examples/info.php
-rw-r--r-- chregu/staff    367 2011-08-15 18:51:10 uploadprogress/config.m4
-rw-r--r-- chregu/staff    303 2011-08-15 18:51:10 uploadprogress/config.w32
-rw-r--r-- chregu/staff   3563 2011-08-15 18:51:10 uploadprogress/php_uploadprogress.h
-rw-r--r-- chregu/staff  15433 2011-08-15 18:51:10 uploadprogress/uploadprogress.c
-rw-r--r-- chregu/staff   1433 2011-08-15 18:51:10 package.xml
```

EDIT: To display the UID and GID from the tar file, add the `--numeric-owner` option.

Comment: Hi @stark. tvf option does not display uid and gid.  I'm chasing down those numbers since  the id can be different between two systems, even though they can be same string.